# AS400 SQL query with Parameter

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I am testing a simple query to get data from an AS400 database. **I am not sure if the way I am using the SQL query is correct.**

I get an error: "The parameter is incorrect."

```
Select FIELD1, FIELD2 From Mylibrary.MyTable WHERE FIELD1 = @Field1
```

I don't get an error when I run the following query:

```
Select FIELD1, FIELD2 From Mylibrary.MyTable WHERE FIELD1 = 'myvalue'
```

I am using ADODB, VBScript to test.

```
Set Param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@Field1", 129, 1, 9, "myvalue")  ' 129 String
cmd.Parameters.Append Param1
```

I am coming from MS Sql environment, so writing for AS400 is totally new for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I got the solution by playing around and trying different things.

As I said before, I am used to OLEDB and ADO.Net so I am used to doing things like:

```
Select FIELD1, FIELD2 From Mylibrary.MyTable WHERE FIELD1 = @Field1
```

which work in Access and SQL Server but not in AS/400.

I got the following to work:

```
Select FIELD1, FIELD2 From Mylibrary.MyTable WHERE FIELD1 = ?

cmd.ActiveConnection = connstr
cmd.CommandType = 1'4   'Stored Procedures '1 Text
cmd.CommandText = sql
Set Param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@Field1", 129, 1, 9, "myvalue")  ' 129 String
cmd.Parameters.Append Param1
Set rs = cmd.Execute()
```

This is all VbScript. The trick was to add the question mark(?) in the sql statement.

Comment: It's standard SQL. From the standard: `In SQL-statements that are executed dynamically, the parameters are called
dynamic parameters (<dynamic parameter specification>s) and are represented in SQL language by a <question
mark> (?).` Microsoft tends to do things differently, which tends to make it harder to work with multiple platforms.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to connect to the AS400 using .NET, first of all you should use the [IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rzaik/rzaikdotnetprovider.htm) .NET provider from IBM. According IBM's [documentation](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246440.html), this is the preferred method for calling sql:

```
iDB2Connection conn = new IDB2Connnection(connectionstring);
iDB2Command cmd = null;

try
{
  conn.Open();
  string sql = "select * from somelibrary.sometable where a = @A and b = @B";
  cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = sql;
  cmd.DeriveParameters(); //this will talk to the AS400 to determine the param types
  cmd.Parameters["@A"].Value = Avalue;
  cmd.Parameters["@B"].Value = Bvalue;

  //execute the query
  cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //doesn't have to be Scalar but you get the idea
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //handle your exceptions
}
finally
{
  cmd.Dispose();
  conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Picflight,

You might have connected using the [system naming conventions instead of SQL naming conventions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/info/db2/rbafzmst39.htm#HDRCH2NAM).  Change Mylibrary.Mytable (SQL period qualifier) to Mylibrary/Mytable (system slash qualifier).